# How do I allow Filezilla or WinSCP to write files to my harddrive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filezilla, winscp

I've been using Windows XP for so long, it just lets me copy files... I'm assuming something security related in Windows 7 needs to be changed so that my FTP programs can write files on my harddrive.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have an FTP server set up?

Comment: No, I'm ftping to a server, i'm just trying to download files from the server I've connected to however the application doesn't have permissions to write to my local harddrive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're running your FTP client in a non-elevated context and you're trying to download files to the hard drive in a folder that is not located in your user profile.  You have 4 choices:

- Download files to a folder within your user profile like c:\users\myusername\downloads
- Run the FTP client in an elevated context (right-click Run As Administrator)
- Manually grant permissions on the folder you're trying to download to.  You need to give write access to either built-in Users group or your specific user account.
- Disable UAC (NOT RECOMMENDED)

Answer (score -1):

Try right-clicking on the shortcut and choosing "Run as administrator". Some programs require this for hardware access.

Comment: Running as administrator should only be used as a last resort, *especially* when we're talking about programs that are downloading files from the internet.

Comment: Because an exploited/virus-infected executable will cause havoc with elevated permissions -- Its OK, it's Windows who taught users the 'wrong' security practices.